# Pixi.js Zoom To Mouse Position

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, mouseevent, pixi.js

I have a scene and we put some sprites inside it.

I have written some code related to Pan, but I need more guidance on this matter.

Now I want to zoom in and out to the location where the mouse is placed.

I have created an example of it:

https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/6PyMNrE95xCTziX01QNE3

```
const { Application, Container, Sprite, Texture } = PIXI

let app, isKeyDown

app = new Application({
    backgroundAlpha: 1,
    width: innerWidth, height: innerHeight,
    antialias: true,
    resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    resizeTo: window,
    autoDensity: true
})
document.body.appendChild(app.view)

const stage = new Container()
app.stage.addChild(stage)

for (let x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    for (let y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
        const box = Sprite.from(Texture.WHITE)
        box.position.set(x * 16, y * 16)
        if (x % 2) box.tint = 0xffff
        if (y % 2) box.tint = 0xfff59
        stage.addChild(box)
    }

let startPos, lastPos, delta
addEventListener('pointerdown', onDown)
addEventListener('pointermove', onMove)
addEventListener('pointerup', onUP)
addEventListener('wheel', onWheel)

function onDown(e) {
    isKeyDown = true
    startPos = { x: e.x, y: e.y }
    lastPos = null
}
function onMove(e) {
    if (!isKeyDown) return
    if (!lastPos) delta = { x: startPos.x - e.x, y: startPos.y - e.y }
    else delta = { x: e.x - lastPos.x, y: e.y - lastPos.y }
    lastPos = { x: e.x, y: e.y }
    stage.x += delta.x
    stage.y += delta.y
}
function onUP(e) {
    isKeyDown = false
}

const smoothZoom = 60
function onWheel(e) {
    const v = e.deltaY < 0 ? 1 : -1
    const s = v * smoothZoom / 1000
    stage.scale.x += s
    stage.scale.y += s
}
```

Comment: You must add the code in the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*

Comment: Also see [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: This may help [Zoom/scale at mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60235061/3877726)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem.

```
const scaleSpeed = 0.1
function onWheel(e) {
    let s = stage.scale.x, tx = (e.x - stage.x) / s, ty = (e.y - stage.y) / s
    s += -1 * Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, e.deltaY)) * scaleSpeed * s
    stage.setTransform(-tx * s + e.x, -ty * s + e.y, s, s)
}
```